# PyCharm permanent clipboard entrie

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm carefully read official PyCharm docs [Cutting, Copying and Pasting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html) and know about clipboard deep but didn't this is not 100% what I need. I want the opportunity to save clipboard entries between session or something like that. I got a complicated string of code and sometimes I want just to paste it from somewhere not bothered about it mandatory presence in the clipboard. How can I do that strange thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a [type of Live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-live-templates.html#live_templates_types).

> *Simple templates* contain only fixed plain text. When you expand a simple template, the text is automatically inserted into your source code, replacing the abbreviation.

To [create a live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Live Templates`, an example is show in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of live templates in settings]

Finally to use the template:

> To expand a code snippet, type the corresponding template abbreviation and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.